# Jacoco Session created Exed shows no Coverage on Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I created a Exec via JacocoAgent on my Local machine (For IT-Testing). Now when I try to upload this Exec to sonarqube, it shows no Coverage.

I built an Ant Task which created an html Report and there I saw, that there was definetely coverage generated. I saw it also in the Jacoco Plugin for Eclipse.

Any Suggestions ?

To execute Sonaranalysis I use Gradle with the "sonar.jacoco.reportpaths" property.

The Log says it is able to read the file (I tried it with the exec, which was generated by Unit Tests and it worked)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details: how did you feed your JaCoCo coverage report into your analysis? What, if anything, did the analysis log say about this report?

Comment: Thank you for the response, Done